Understanding two-stage feedback amplifier

Image from ELECTRONIC PRINCIPLES 8TH EDITION BY ALBERT MALVINO AND DAVID BATES, PAGE 332
Guys i try to understand this circuit but i got stuck.
According to my assumption:
Let's say rf = 360 ohm

Av = (rf/re) + 1 so gain equals 3

If Vout equals 3*Vin then ac emitter voltage of first stage equals Vin because of the voltage divider.
If ac emitter voltage is Vin then Vout of the first stage equals Vin meaning that there is no voltage gain in first stage. Right?
But if input voltage of second stage is Vin how could it equal 3*Vin as output voltage of second stage?

Why do you think thta Av=[(rf/re) + 1] ? Such an expression is valid for a non-inverting amplifier with an infinite open-loop gain only (typical case: opamp).

This is a non-inverting amplifier.

@ gencer - May I ask you why the emitter resistor of Q1 is designated as "re" ? I suppose, it is an external (static) resistor Re=180 ohms.

First stage is a swamped amplifier. When there is large input signal most of the voltage will be across the re instead of internal resistance of emitter diode r'e. re reduces distortion of emitter current. It acts like a negative feedback reducing voltage across Vbe. Good swamped amplifier needs r'e < 0.1re. As i said r'e is internal resistance of emitter diode and equals 25mV/IE and it is 22.7 ohm in this circuit.

@ gencer - No I know what you mean. I think it is very misleading and causes many misunderstandings, when you mix classic (linear, static) circuit elements with non-linear/differential (artificial) quantities like re=1/gm. As a result: You are in error because this artificial quantity re will NOT cause any negative feedback and, hence, it will not reduce distortion. For this reason, I never recommend to use such a notation. The quantity re is neither part of the emitter nor it is a resistance at all. It is nothing else than the inverse transconductance (slope of the Ic=f(Vbe) characteristic.

continued: My correspondence with Simon Fitch (see below)  was caused by the misunderstanding you have created using such a quantitty re in your diagram. More than tha,t the value of re=180 is very unrealistic and misleading (as we have seen).

@ gencer - I forgot to state clearly: You circuit diagram (as far as the feedback path is concerned) is wrong. The feedback path must be connected BETWEEN the quantity re and RE1 (because you consider re as part of the transistor). However, in this case, the feedback signal is shorted by CE.

To make understand how this can be, you should simulate it ...
Made with microcap v12

You can see how Vip is reduced.

That is not correct. The first stage amplifies the error signal, in other words, the original vin minus the vin form by the divider.
Negative feedback amplifiers take the error signal as an input and produce an output such that this error signal is maximally suppressed at the input. The ideal case is that both (+) and (-) terminals are equal, which is, basically, one of the op-amp golden rules.

Your circuit consists of a two-stage transistor amplifier with an oen-loop gain Aol and a feedback loop having a transfer funktion Af.
In such a case, the closed-loop (overall) gain is Acl=Aol/(1+Aol*Af)
In this expression, the term Aol*Af is identical to the so-called "loop gain Alg" which can be found by open the feedback loop at a suitable node for injecting a testsignal (set input voltage at the base of Q1 equal to zero).

This is indeed a non-inverting amplifier, and gain will be approximately \$1+\frac{R_F}{R_E}\approx 3\$. You are almost correct in your assessment that fluctuations of potential at Q1's emitter will be equal to fluctuations of \$V_{IN}\$; in fact the fluctuations will be almost equal. This does not mean, however, that there's nothing to amplify. They are almost equal, meaning there is still a non-zero something to amplify, albeit a very small something.
The signal being amplified is the potential difference between Q1's base and emitter \$V_{BE}=V_B-V_E\$. Feedback is applied to emitter (and subtracted, so it's negative feedback), source signal is applied to base. The combined AC voltage gain of stage 1 (Q1) and stage 2 (Q2) will be over 100, but let's say exactly 100 for the sake of argument, and that's actual gain from input to output.
The thing is, for any change in input of say 1mV, you expect to see 100mV of change at the output, since that's the gain from input to output, in either case, with or without negative feedback. I'll put that another way; regardless of the presence or absence or amount of feedback, Q1 and Q2 still multiply a change in \$V_{BE}\$ by 100. That's the so-called "open-loop gain". It's what an oscilloscope would show you if you measured and compared changes in \$V_{BE}\$ and \$V_{OUT}\$.
When \$V_B\$ changes, it's true that \$V_E\$ also changes, but not by 100% of the change in \$V_B\$, rather by just under 100%. That tiny remaining difference is what's being amplified by Q1 and Q2 (×100), and what appears at the output.
When using op-amps with negative feedback, open-loop gain is over 105 (not a paltry 100 like here) and we often claim that the inverting and non-inverting inputs are equal. They are not, they are still different, but by mere microvolts. It is those microvolts of difference which the op-amp is mutliplying by 105, to produce whole volts at the output.

I understand your explanation about Q1 amplifiying something non-zero ac voltage accross Vbe. I think that is because some Vin voltage drops accross the internal resistance of emitter diode which is r'e. But what i am asking here is if Q2 amplifies let's say 100 times of it's input. Wouldn't it be 100 times Vin instead 3 times Vin which i mentioned in my question.

@ gencer - the gain of the 2nd stage will be much lower than 100. Don`t forget that the output of Q2 is loaded also by the (low resistive) feedback path. My rough calculations result in a gain of app. "22". The gain of Q1 (loaded by the input resistance of the 2nd stage) is app. "7" (without feedback from Q2).  Hence, the open-loop gain is app. Aol=155.

@gencer Don't confuse $V_{IN}$ and $V_{BE(Q1)}$. $V_{IN}$ is ground referenced,  but it is potential difference $V_{BE}=V_B-V_E$ that is amplified by Q1. $V_E$ isn't fixed as it would be without feedback. Feedback changes everything, but Q1 still multiplies $V_{BE}$ by $g_mR_{C1}$.

@ Simon Fitch - May I ask you why you are able to state that the gain would be app. (1+Rf/Re) ? I think, the input resistance at the emitter of Q1 is Re||(1/gm1), which is much lower than Re.

@LvW It's just the non-inverting gain formula, and this is a non inverting arrangement with negative feedback. Negative feedback eliminates a lot of complications (such as non-linearity and high output impedance), and lots of complications go away. Everything simplifies to $A=1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}$. Well, nearly, the system is far from ideal.

@ Simon Fitch - this was not my question. This gain formula is applicable for an opamp with a high-resistive inverting input (feedback path: R2-R1). However, in the circuit under discussion the inverting input has a low input resistance. Hence, the feedback voltage at this input must take into consideration the parallel combination (1/gm1)||180 ohms  (gm1=transconductance of Q1 which is app 45 mS)

@LvW Your point about the low impedance at the emitter is true, so that gain formula won't work if Q2's collector resistance can't source enough current to raise Q1's emitter potential, or Q2 and its emitter resistances can sink enough. Consequently in practice output swing will be heavily truncated, and $A=1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}$ can only be maintained within those constraints.

@LvW the same op-amp behaviour can be expected for small enough signals, though, where the two input potentials, base and emitter will equalise (or in this case be maintained 0.7V apart, like an op-amp with a horrible input offset voltage), but adherence to $A=1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}$ gets much worse for higher gains. I think a simulation will show this well, for A=3, not so much for A>10.

@Simon Fitch - of course, all the mentioned formulas are valid only when the whole circuit works in its quasi-linear region. Within these limits, the feedback signal for Q1 is developped across Re||(1/gm1). Do you agree?

continued: Now I have learned that the quantitty "re" in the given diagram is equivalent to 1/gm1. I have commented this misleading notation - which has caused a misunderstanding between us (you have also considered Re as an external resistor). More than that, the given value of re=180 ohms corresponds to a current of app. Ic=0.13mA. However, this low value does not correspond to the given values for the base voltage divider.
